# How to display custom password character with some delay like EditText control

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-edittext

I have created a custom control by inheriting the EditText control. My requirements are to display the custom password character and when typing there should be some delay like EditText when setting the **input type**. I have achieved the custom password character displaying but I am unable to achieve the second requirement. I tried to achieve the second requirement by using **PostDelay**. When typing a single character I can have some delay before it changes to password character but when typing multiple characters fastly I cant able to achieve the requirement similar to edit text control. I have attached the sample in the below link: https://github.com/Eswaran17392/CustomSamples/blob/master/CustomEditbox.zip. Anyone, please suggest me how to achieve the delay similar to EditText. For applying delay, I used below code snippet:

```
if(ShowPasswordDelay)
{
Java.Lang.Runnable runnable = new Java.Lang.Runnable(() =>
                    {
                        this.Text = value;
                    });
                    if (handler != null)
                    {
                        handler.RemoveCallbacks(runnable);
                        handler = null;
                        this.Text = value;            
}

if (handler == null)
handler = new Handler();
handler.PostDelayed(runnable, 1000);
}
else
{
     this.Text = value;
}
```

Comment: why you want to set delay,there is a delay in setting the inputtype to the password of the edittext on the system.you could just custom your password character.

Answer (score 0):

here is a sample to custom your password character:

1.create **PasswordCharSequence** class :

```
class PasswordCharSequence : Java.Lang.Object, ICharSequence
{
    private ICharSequence mSource;

    public PasswordCharSequence(ICharSequence mSource)
    {
        this.mSource = mSource;
    }
    public char CharAt(int index)
    {
        return '*'; // here is your custom password character
    }
    public IEnumerator<char> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return mSource.GetEnumerator();
    }
    public int Length()
    {
        return mSource.Length();
    }

    public ICharSequence SubSequenceFormatted(int start, int end)
    {
        return mSource.SubSequenceFormatted(start,end);
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return mSource.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

2.create **CustomPasswordTransformationMethod** class :

```
class CustomPasswordTransformationMethod : PasswordTransformationMethod
    {
        public override ICharSequence GetTransformationFormatted(ICharSequence source, View view)
```

3.set EditText like:

```
EditText edit = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.edit);
edit.TransformationMethod = new CustomPasswordTransformationMethod();
```